# How can I delete the rows using Filter Function in R?

Tags: r

My Dataset,  card.usage is like the followings.

```
> head(card.usage)
     dateYmd WithdrawMoney DepositMoney         title     extra
1 2016-08-18         10000            0       국민조*기   인터넷
2 2016-08-17          7300            0 롯데쇼핑（주）롯 체크우리
3 2016-08-17          2500            0   메가박스（주） 체크우리
4 2016-08-17             0        20000             조**   모바일
5 2016-08-17          4200            0 서울모스 체크우리
6 2016-08-14          2400            0 （주）코리아세븐 체크우리
```

With this dataset to be need to be fixed, I want to use Filter function to remove the row where the column depositMoney is 0, So I tried running the following code

```
card.usage.filtered = Filter( function(x) {  x$DepositMoney = 0}, card.usage)
```

what I want to do is to delete the rows where the column, DepositMoney, is not 0. But If I use the filter function like above, I lose all rows.  I know that the parameter of high order function is a vector . How can I access the specific column ? I can not find the example of it.

Comment: I think you need `subset` or `filter` from `dplyr` i.e. `subset(card.usage, DepositMoney ==0)`

Comment: @akrun Those are different from Filter function above?

Comment: With `Filter`, you can subset the columns

Answer (score 4):

We can use `subset` from `base R`

```
card.usage.filtered <-  subset(card.usage, DepositMoney ==0)
```

---

Or `filter` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
card.usage %>%
         filter(DepositMoney == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this base-r feature.

```
card.usage.filtered <- card.usage[card.usage$DepositMoney==0,]
```